# Getting error while adding new item in FormLibrary in AppWeb Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, app-web

When I publish  my InfoPath form to AppWeb Library it is successfully deployed but when I click on Add New Item in InfoPath Form it is giving me error

> The endpoint /sites/tssrnd/infopathappweb/_layouts/15/formserver.aspx
>   is not accessible in the context of a SharePoint App.

Please help me out for this issue.